# Prevent JQuery Mobile from closing a popup when user taps outside of it

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, modal-dialog

I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.2.0 alpha 1.

Currently, when I open a popup and tap outside of it anywhere on the screen the popup is being closed. 
I was wondering if there's any JQuery Mobile attribute I have missed which can be set and prevent closing the popup upon outside-tap? (modal popup)

(The documentation for popups can be found [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html))

**EDIT:**

I had an idea of solving this but still can't implement it to work:

When a JQM popup show up theres a div which covers all of the screen with class of ui-popup-screen. I thought somehow to give it a large z-index and unbind all click/tap function from it. Doing this does not solve my problem but I guess it is a small step in the direction.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This has been added as a feature request on Github. See issue [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4727).

As a hack for this in the interim is to unbind the events on the ui-popup-screen. I would put the following code in the pageinit.

```
$("#yourPopupId").on({
    popupbeforeposition: function () {
        $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
    }
});
```

This is a heavy handed quickfix, but it works.

Comment: Do you know how I can make it so that the background is still enabled? :) I cannot dismiss it, but also I cannot interact with the rest anymore.

Comment: @MJB I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. Could you elaborate on what you still want to interact with?

Comment: I have a map in the background. I want a popup (sidebar) to appear with some controls (buttons) and actions the user issues when he clicks a button and then on the map.

Comment: And you want to be able to use the map while the popup is open?

Comment: This does not work when the popup has the data-history="false" attribute :(

Answer (score 19):

For future searchers, as of 1.3, this is now supported. Simply add the `data-dismissible="false"` attribute to the panel div.

Comment: I have 1.7.13, but adding that attribute to my div does nothing. Wonder what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Building on @TheGwa's excellent solution, here's a generalization to prepare for the upcoming official feature (presumably, in version 1.3):

- Add `data-dismissible='false'` to the markup of all popups that you don't want to be dismissible by tapping outside of them.
- Add the following event handler to your app; it will handle all popups:

_

```
$(window).on('popupbeforeposition', 'div:jqmData(role="popup")', function() {
        var notDismissible = $(this).jqmData('dismissible') === false;
        if (notDismissible) {
          $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
        }
});
```

-

Once the feature is officially supported, simply remove the event handler.

Note that, sadly, the official documentation (as of 1.2) suggests that the feature is already available, but it is not - see http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/options.html

Answer (score 0):

Add data-dismissible="false" in following way.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupnotification" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="c"  data-position-to="window" style="max-width:600px;">
```

Comment: What do we add it to. could you please show an example

Answer (score 0):

@ MJB -> If you want to be able to click anywhere (e.g. on a button) when a pop-up is active, you can alter the CSS of the pop-up as follows:

```
.ui-popup-screen{
                    position: relative;
                }
```

This worked for me.

**Note:** Pop-up does not close on click anymore when you do this - I made a workaround:

```
$(window).click(function() {    
    if ($( "#myPopup-popup" ).hasClass("ui-popup-active")){
        $( "#myPopup" ).popup( "close" );
    }
});
```

the myPopup-popup ID is generated by JQM - myPopup is the ID I gave the pop-up.