# Jquery Mobile Global Popup Background

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, popup

i got a problem with my app.i'm developing an app with cordova & jquery mobile.
Following the code on jquery mobile master i found that code

```
function openPopup(idPopup, onTimeout) {
    var popupContent = '<div data-role="content" data-theme="a" style="border:0px;" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content centerContent">' +
        '<h3 class="ui-title" id="myTitle">Caricamento</h3>' +
        '<img src="img/load_shop33sell.gif"/></div>';
    var popup = '<div data-role="popup" id="popup-' + idPopup + '" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" class="ui-content">' + popupContent + '</div>';
    $.mobile.activePage.append(popup).trigger("pagecreate");
    $("#popup-" + idPopup).on({
        popupbeforeposition: function () {
            $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
        }
    });
    var fallback = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#popup-" + idPopup).popup("open");
    }, 3000);
    $("#popup-" + idPopup).popup("open");
    clearTimeout(fallback);
    callback = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#popup-" + idPopup).popup('close');
        if (onTimeout && typeof (onTimeout) === "function") {
            onTimeout();
        }
    }, 20000);
}
```

With this code, i am able to open a popup without needing to include a

```
<div data-role="popup">..../<div>
```

in each page i create.I just modified a bit adding the popupbeforeposition event to make the popup undismissable by clicking on the background.
Well, it works fine but i got a problem. Randomly in my first page this happens

[image: First image]

Seems like the popup opens before it get the right position. In addition i have a second page which is scrollable, and i always have this situation. If i try to scroll up to the top of the page, i have half of the screen black, as in first picture.
[image]

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english :)

Comment: `.trigger("create");` is enough, you dont need to call `.trigger("pagecreate");`. This might not solve the problem, but just a note :)

Comment: this seems that partially solved my problem. Now the situation as in #1 screenshot is no more happening, but in  #2 screenshot is still happening that annoying think. Seems like the background is ok simply in the portion of the screen which i'm looking at, if i try to scroll up or down half of the screen is black....trying to lock the scroll of the screen could be a workaround to fix that?

Comment: still having this problem :(

Comment: When opening a popup, try calling `$.mobile.activePage.trigger('updatelayout');`.

Comment: the problem seems to be caused by the  `data-overlay-theme="a"` attribute given to the popup..if i remove it, the background is shown in a good way..btw i'd need to solve this keeping a black background..there are other way to do that instead of `data-overlay-theme="a"` on the popup?

Comment: Try overriding `.ui-popup-overlay-a`

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned it is due to `data-overlay-theme="a"`. But actually it should works in good way..thinking that this is due to `$('.ui-popup-screen').off();`
you can observe here
[Prevent JQuery Mobile from closing a popup when user taps outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246181/prevent-jquery-mobile-from-closing-a-popup-when-user-taps-outside-of-it)

if you need an alternative way for black background you can do this ..

Add div `<div id="overlaypage"></div>` like this inside `<div data-role="page">`

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div id="overlaypage"></div>
  <div id="header"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlaycont {
    background:#000;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:100;
    opacity:.6
}
```

jQuery:

- When you try to click to open a popup addclass

  ```
  $("#overlaypage").addClass("overlaycont");
  ```
- When you closing the popup remove class

  ```
  $("#overlaypage").removeClass("overlaycont");
  ```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nPeaV/7421/

Comment: uhmm the only problem is that, if try to tap out the popup without hitting "close" button, the popup closes and remains the  black background, with no way to remove it..

Comment: according to the post you mentioned, i removed the `//$("#popup-" + idPopup).on({
       popupbeforeposition: function () {
            $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
       }
    });` and i've added `data-dismissible="false"` on the div, it works for preventing the popup to be closed tapping outside, but  the effect was the same..still a black bar on the left

Answer (score 2):

ok, i solved the problem combining the two answers, this is my function to open popup

```
    function apriPopup(idPopup, onTimeout) {
            $(".ui-navbar").css('display','none');
            var popupContent = '<div data-role="content" data-theme="a" style="border:0px;" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content centerContent">' +
                '<h3 class="ui-title" id="myTitle">Caricamento</h3>' +
                '<img src="img/load_shop33sell.gif"/></div>';
            var popup = '<div data-role="popup" data-dismissible="false" id="popup-' + idPopup + '" data-theme="a" class="ui-content">' + popupContent + '</div>';
            $.mobile.activePage.append(popup).trigger("create");
            //$("#popup-" + idPopup).on({
            //    popupbeforeposition: function () {
            //   $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
            //    }
            //});
            var fallback = setTimeout(function () {
                $("#overlaypage").addClass("overlaycont");
                $("#popup-" + idPopup).popup("open");
            }, 3000);
            $("#overlaypage").addClass("overlaycont");
            $("#popup-" + idPopup).popup("open");
            clearTimeout(fallback);
            callback = setTimeout(function () {
            $(".ui-navbar").css('display','block');
                $("#overlaypage").removeClass("overlaycont");
                $("#popup-" + idPopup).popup('close');
                if (onTimeout && typeof (onTimeout) === "function") {
                    onTimeout();
                }
            }, 20000);
        }
```

as you can see i have commentend the `$('.ui-popup-screen').off();` , added a `data-dismissable="false"`
and i have used the overlaycont css style suggested by dileep.

in my index, as child of body,i added a `<div id="overlaypage"></div>` and `$("#overlaypage").addClass("overlaycont");`, 
in this way popup is undismissabile by cliking outside of it, and background is displayed correctly.

such a pain!